# asp.net mvc 3 c# post array of variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to pass array to POST method. But i'm obviously missing sometging
My view look something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Klausimynas.Models.Rezultat>" %>

<input type="text" name="x[1]">
<input type="text" name="x[2]">
<input type="text" name="x[3]">
<input type="text" name="x[4]">
<input type="text" name="x[5]">
<input type="text" name="x[6]">
<input type="text" name="x[7]">
```

My method declaration looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LetsTest(IEnumerable<Rezultat> rez)
```

and when i'm trying to extract data i'm getting Value can't be null.
What i'm missing?

Comment: To what property of `rez` are you trying to bind these fields? You can't bind a textbox value to a complex type. Unless your property is `rez.x`, this won't work.

Comment: To int, but i changed it to string i get the same result

Comment: But what is the property of the `Rezultat` object that you are trying to bind to?

Comment: this is the property:
public string x { get; set; }

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you need. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of things wrong here:

1. Your view is typed to `Rezultat` but you're trying to treat the model as an `IEnumerable<Rezultat>`.
2. You're trying to bind each textbox to `x[i]` - which would be equivalent to `Model.x[i]` - when what you really want is to bind it to `[i].x` (i.e. `Model[i].x`).

So, to correct this, you need to change a couple of things.

First, change your view to inherit `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Klausimynas.Models.Rezultat>>`. Now your view can pass an `IEnumerable<Rezultat>`, which is what your controller action expects.

Second, change this:

```
<input type="text" name="x[0]">
```

To this:

```
<input type="text" name="[0].x">
```

The reason for this is that the first will attempt to bind the value to `Model.x[0]`, which is (or will be, once you've typed your view properly) equivalent to the first element in property `x` of an instance of `IEnumerable<Rezultat>`. This obviously isn't quite right, as an `IEnumerable` exposes no property `x`. What you want is to bind `Model[0].x`, which is the property `x` of the `Rezultat` object at index `0`.

Better still, use a helper to generate the name for you:

```
for(int i=0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].x)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really wnat to do it this way you have to use I think Form Collection

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LetsTest(FormCollection collection, IEnumerable<Rezultat> rez)
{

    string[] inputs = new string[6];
    for(int i=1; i<8; i++)
   {
       //get all your array inputs
       inputs[i-1]=collection["x["+i+"]"]
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out model binding to a list [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx). Items posted needs to be in certain format to be able to retrieve them as list in POST action.

Answer (score 0):

Change your view code as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Klausimynas.Models.Rezultat>" %>

<input type="text" name="x[0]" />
<input type="text" name="x[1]" />
<input type="text" name="x[2]" />
<input type="text" name="x[3]" />
<input type="text" name="x[4]" />
<input type="text" name="x[5]" />
<input type="text" name="x[6]" />
```

**Update**: On 2nd thoughts, I think this is your actual problem, you are starting from 1-7, rather than 0-6.

Thanks Ant.

Comment: You anticipate that an instance of `Rezultat` has an indexable property called `rez`? I think this needs a rethink.

Comment: Ant... I think all that's wrong is the indexing. The DefaultModelBinder will try to match the input value to the property of the type, `Rezultat` in this case, but it is very sensitive to the indexes specified. They have to start from 0 and have to be contiguous.

Comment: I disagree that that's what the problem is. Your solution implies that he is trying to pass `Rezultat.x[0]` through `Rezultat.x[n-1]`, when from careful reading of the question it is clear - as my answer details -  that he actually wants to pass `Model[0].x` through `Model[n-1].x`, where `Model` is an `IEnumerable<Rezultat>`.