# Passing an ID from Razor view to Controller

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, nullreferenceexception

In a view of type List I'm trying to pass the id (which is an eMail in this case) of the item from the view to an actionResult in the controller: I used the following code():

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "CreateMessage", "Member", new { id = item.eMail })
```

I get a null reference because the id passed is null.

Here's the view which works just fine and the id in it isn't null:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mutuelle.Domain.Entities.Adherent>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "lister";
}

<h2>Liste des adhérents</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <body style="overflow:scroll;">
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dateOfBirth)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.address)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.phoneNumber)
            </th>
            <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>


            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateOfBirth)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phoneNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Contacter", "CreateMessage", "MembreComite", new { id = item.eMail })

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateMessage(string id)
        {
            Message message = new Message();
            return View(message);

        }
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateMessage(Message message, string id)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AMDMService service = new AMDMService();

                Member member = service.GetMemberByeMail(id);
                message.member = member;

                message.adherentId = id;



                member.listMessages.Add(message);

                return RedirectToAction("listeMessages");

            }
            return View(message);

        }
```

Comment: where exacly error is?

Comment: this is the line causing the null reference error(cannot insert the value NULL into the column adherentId): 'message.adherentId = id;' because the id that is being passed from the view is NULL

Comment: Is this a form POST submission? Where is the rest of the form? Watch the request with the browser's network monitor -- What does the request body look like? Does it match your action signature? Also, `foreach` when sending collections rarely work together. Use a `for` loop instead. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501118/asp-net-mvc-3-c-sharp-post-array-of-variables).

Comment: This is the entire form. "for" doesn't work, it causes an error, the view was automatically generated using the type "List" is strongly typed to the entity "member"

Comment: If you are trying to hit the GET action the override you are using is wrong: `ActionLink(linkText, action, controller, htmlAttributes)` rather than `ActionLink(linkText, action, controller, routeValues, htmlAttributes)`.

Comment: @Jasen Thank you the probel was indeed with the html.actionLink

Comment: change `@Html.ActionLink("Contacter", "CreateMessage", "MembreComite", new { id = item.eMail })` to `@Html.ActionLink("Contacter", "CreateMessage", "MembreComite", new { id = item.eMail },null)`. It will work

Answer (score 2):

When you use routeValues like `new { id = item.eMail }` in your ActionLink, then you **always** should provide value for `html attributes`, which mostly used for styling your link, so if you don't want to style your link then you pass `null` otherwise you pass something like that `new { @class = "btn btn-rounded btn-blue" }`). So your code for `ActionLink` should look like this if you don't want to style your link:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "CreateMessage", "Member", new { id = item.eMail }, null);
```

Also you can replace `@Html.ActionLink` helper with `@Url.Action` helper like below:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CreateMessage", "Member", new { id = item.eMail })"> Contact</a>
```