# ASP.NET MVC: How to insert multiple "EditorFor" into database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

If I click on "+", a new textbox with "x" will be displayed. If I click on "x", that synonym row will be removed. My problem for now is how to save all these synonyms into database. So the database should look like:

```
SynonymID  Synonym    CAS No.
    1      Synonym1     1
    2      Synonym2     1
    3      Synonym3     1
```

Now it only save the first one.
From this example http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/. It let me use "BeginCollectionItem", but it says my model does not contain a definition of "BeginCollectionItem".

Can anyone help me solve this? Or is there any other way to do it?

This is the Chemical Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(NPG_ChemicalViewModel model)
    {
        using (var context = new NPG_Model())
        {
            var chemical = new NPG_Chemical();

            chemical.CAS_Number = model.NPG_Chemical.CAS_Number;
            context.NPG_Chemical.Add(chemical);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var synonym = new NPG_Chemical_Synonym();
            synonym.Synonym = model.NPG_Chemical_Synonym.Synonym;
            context.NPG_Chemical_Synonym.Add(synonym);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var initialData = new[] {
             new NPG_Chemical_Synonym { Synonym = "" },
            };
        }
    return View();
    }

    public ViewResult BlankEditorRow()
    {
        return View("GiftEditorRow", new NPG_ChemicalViewModel());
    }
```

This is the create.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4 align="center">Add Chemical</h4>
    <hr />
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>Synonym</td>
            <td>
                <div id="editorRows">
                        @{Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow");}
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.ActionLink("+", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CAS No.</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NPG_Chemical.CAS_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NPG_Chemical.CAS_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <script>
       $("#addItem").click(function () {
           $.ajax({
               url: this.href,
               cache: false,
               success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
           });
           return false;
       });
       </script>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

and this is the BlankEditorRow.cshtml:

```
<div class="editorRow">
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">x</a>
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NPG_Chemical_Synonym.Synonym)
</div>
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a.deleteRow', function () {
    $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

This is NPG_ChemicalViewModel:

```
namespace NPG_Administrative_Utility.Models
{
public class NPG_ChemicalViewModel
{
    public NPG_ChemicalViewModel()
    {
        NPG_Chemical = new NPG_Chemical();
        NPG_Chemical_Synonym = new NPG_Chemical_Synonym();
    }
    public NPG_Chemical NPG_Chemical { get; set; }
    public NPG_Chemical_Synonym NPG_Chemical_Synonym { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is Synonym model:

```
namespace NPG_Administrative_Utility.Models
{
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class NPG_Chemical_Synonym
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public decimal NPG_Chemical_Synonym_ID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal NPG_Chemical_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(512)]
    public string Synonym { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: What does your `NPG_ChemicalViewModel` look like? Also see how to [post a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501118/asp-net-mvc-3-c-sharp-post-array-of-variables).

Comment: @Jasen Please see the update.

Comment: 1) The way you dynamically add form items, each item has identical `name` attributes (look at the rendered html), so when you submit the form binding won't recognize your multiple items. See the linked question in my previous comment. 2) So, you'll need to provide an index for your items e.g. `name="NPG_ChemicalViewModel[0].NPG_Chemical"` 3) Your view model needs a collection of related Synonyms or change the action signature `Create(decimal chemId, NPG_Chemical_Synonym[] synonyms)`

Comment: You need to work through the tutorial again. Nowhere in you code have you used `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem())` to generate the correct html. Even you model is incorrect - you don't have a collection property to hold tthe dynamically created items

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `ICollection<Synonym>` to your model and  Use for each loop in your view.
you could have as many as `EditorFor` inside your view and you could hide/show them by jQuery. Model binding will find all `Synonyms` for you! and you could handle that in your controller.