# ASP.NET views and model, a small questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Dears,

Please could you help me to understand very simple thing

I have model with my class:

```
public class VendorAssistanceViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
public partial class CSModel : IEntity
{
    public CSModel()
    {

        VendorAssistances = new[]
        {
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "DJ/BAND" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Officiant" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Florist" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Photographer" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Videographer" },
        new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Transportation" },
        }.ToList();
    }


    public IList VendorAssistances { get; set; }
```

I have view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CSTS.Models.CSModel>

 //some html code...
```

I want to know how  to show array of checkboxes from Model, using VendorAssistances ?
I know that this is very simple, I read a lot of docs, but still can not understand

Thank you!

UPDATED

I tried to do follow:

1. Into Control in

   ```
            public override ActionResult Index(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string   nothing)
     {

     List<VendorAssistanceViewModel> VendorAssistances = new[]
   {
   new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "DJ/BAND" },
   new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Officiant" },
   new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Florist" },
   new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Photographer" },
   new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Videographer" },
   new VendorAssistanceViewModel { Name = "Transportation" },
   }.ToList();
   ```

I've added Watch to VendorAssistances and insert breakpoint, and all time tihs object is NULL

why ?

Comment: why do you use partial class for CSModel?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d9083/creating-simple-checkboxlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Comment: Unfortunatelly can answer, this is code of one ASP.NET site, and required to do some changes here

Answer (score 1):

you just need to iterate over the `Model.VendorAssistances` and emit html code for each `VendorAssistanceViewModel`.You can use this code:

```
@foreach(var model in Model)
{
    for(int i=0; i < model .VendorAssistances.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => model.VendorAssistances[i].Name)
    }
}
```

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501118/asp-net-mvc-3-c-sharp-post-array-of-variables) question that can help you undedrerstand how to post the generated array to an action.

Comment: Thanks, but appear error message CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CSD.Models.CSModel >' does not contain a definition for 'VendorAssistances' and no extension method 'VendorAssistances' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CSD.Models.CSModel >' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you please try if it works for you. And please don't forget to mark as answer if it does :)

Comment: Yes ( it seems that view cannot find property of VendorAssistances

Comment: When hitting the breakpoint what fields are available in Model and Model[0] ?